# Riemann-Stieltjes integral of a function integer part

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

Let $g(t)=\lfloor t\rfloor$, and $f(t)=\frac1{t^\alpha+1}$ with $\alpha\neq1$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb R$. Find the value of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int^n_1f(t)\,\mathrm dg(t)$ if it exists, where $n \in \Bbb Z$ is fixed.

I know, that integrating by parts gives
$$
\int^{n}_{1} f dg = \int^{n}_{1} \frac{d \lfloor t \rfloor}{t^{\alpha}+1} = \frac{n}{n^{\alpha}+1}-\frac{1}{2}+ \alpha \int^{n}_{1} \frac{\lfloor t \rfloor t^{\alpha -1}}{(t^{\alpha }+1)^2}dt
$$
I would like to know if the procedure is ok, although I am confused with the final result. I appreciate the help

Comment: Thank you, but do you think that integral is easy to calculate, I mean that two options emerge, right?

Comment: You may try to split the integral as $\sum^n_{j=2}\int^j_{j-1}$

Comment: in each piece you get 
$$\int^j_{j-1}\frac{[t]t^{\alpha-1}}{(t^\alpha+1)^2}dt=(j-1)\int^j_{j-1}\frac{t^{\alpha-1}}{(t^\alpha+1)^2}dt$$ which can then be computed by substitution.

Comment: A more direct computation is to notice that the measure $\mu(dt)=d[t]=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta_{n}$ and so $$\int\mathbb{1}_{(1,n]}(t)\,f(t)\,d[t]=\sum_{1<k\leq n}f(k)$$

Comment: I am computing the firs integral in the comments, but so $\frac{n}{n^{\alpha}+1}-\frac{1}{2}+ \alpha \int^{n}_{1} \frac{\lfloor t \rfloor t^{\alpha -1}}{(t^{\alpha }+1)^2}dt = \sum_{1<t\le n}  \frac{1}{(t^{\alpha }+1)^2}$?

Comment: It may be that you are also considering the endpoint $1$ (notice that in my previous formula I don't include $1$). the additional $1$ good give $f(1)=\frac12$.